# Filtering for specific associations in Gramps

Tags: gramps

Godparents have an important role in my family and, as advised in Gramps, I list such associations under the tab Association.

However, I find myself able to filter individuals only by number of associations (how many people have x number of associations), when I need to locate all godparents (or all godchildren, or whatever other association).

Is there a way to personalise a filter to do what I need?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create a customised filter for godfathers using "People with record containing " and substring -> "godfather".